# fopen, fwrite and fclose file size issue

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fclose

I'm using fopen, fwrite and fclose to save a PNG onto my server using this code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
$f = fopen('../../myFolder/myImage.png', 'w+'); 
fwrite($f, base64_decode($lowerDesign)); 
$success = fclose($f);
echo $success != false ? '1' : '0';
```

Now this works perfectly for small file sizes (1-5kb) but fails for larger images. I'm getting absolutely no errors in my logs whatsoever. All I get is a '0' instead of a '1' and there is no PNG saved.

Obviously, the file size is the issue but I can't think of how to get around it.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should probably try writing in chunks, or use `file_put_contents()`

Answer (score 1):

Split $lowerDesign into small chunks, base64_decode() has issues with large amounts of data

Comment: OK I have done this. The same problem exists for larger files. In Firebug I can see this traced out:

... Firebug request size limit has been reached by Firebug. ...

I think the base64 encoded string is too large to be sent to my PHP script. Has anyone come across this before? What can be done?